# Issue on Validating An array of Inputs in Meta Box

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am trying to validate a group of data input for different posts as

> $post_types = array ( 'movieCPT', 'bookCPT', 'paperCPT' );

so far I have a function which work correct individually for each of the options as

```
function save_options()
{
    global $post;
      if (!isset($_POST['source']) || $post->post_type != 'movieCPT')
    {
        return $post;
    }
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "source", $_POST['source']);

}
```

now can you please let me know how to pass an object for array `$post_types` instead of `movieCPT` in

> if (!isset($_POST['source']) || $post->post_type != 'movieCPT')

Thanks

**Update**

```
function save_options()
{
 $post_types = array ( 'movieCPT', 'bookCPT', 'paperCPT' );
    global $post;
   $cpt =   $post->post_type;

    if ((!isset($_POST['source'])) || (! in_array( $cpt, $post_types )))
    {
        return $post;
    }
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "source", $_POST['source']);

}
```

Comment: you want to check whether `$post->post_type` is not inside `$post_types`?

Comment: Hi Ghost yeah exactly, which  in that case there is no update in the post

Comment: your update is already okay i guess, just use `in_array()`. actually thats what i was going to asnwer

Comment: I also tried to use the `!in_array()` function which didn't work please take a look at update for this

Comment: you mean without `!` ?

Comment: nope, your answer i'll implement it just like that `not in array` => `!in_array()`: just make sure there are no extra spaces on the string `$post->type`. also check if they share the same upper/lowercase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63386/discussion-between-suffii-and-ghost).

Comment: How `save_options` is called?